# Looks like you try to load a template outside configured directories (../includeFiles/header.html.twig) Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to separate templates, and take out the header, and when connecting

```
   {{include ('../includeFiles/header.html.twig')}}
```

in the profile.html.twig file I have this error, I checked, in the twig.yaml file

```
twig:
     default_path: '% kernel.project_dir% / templates'
```

here is my template hierarchy:

description of the template hierarchy

[image: template hierarchy]

I don't understand what the mistake is, I will be very grateful for the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twig do not allow to use `../` inside template names. You should use [Namespaced Twig Paths](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/templating/namespaced_paths.html).